# Android LinearLayout items overlap each other when one changes visibillity properties

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a view with a LinearLayout which contains a bunch of items to show.
In initialization code I add these items into layout.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    View view = new SwitchButton(mTexts.get(i));
    mLinearLayout.add(view);
}
```

On top of this LinearLayout I have a TabLayout with several tabs. Whenever a user switches to another tab I set visibility property to each item in the layout according to to a specific tab.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {
    if (tab.getPosition() != mLastSelectedTab) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View item = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (isVisibleInTab(tab.getPosition(), i) {
                 item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                 item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when a user changes tab for a short period of time linear layout items overlap one another. Even if I set

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

in my layout, overlapping still occurs.

Comment: We can't just help you with this two code blocks. Can u share few more code of your XML where you defined `LinearLayout` and `TabLayout`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant since LinearLayout is defined empty with default parameters and later filled with views from code, which I presented, while tab layout is a completely separate widget and you could replace it with Spinner for example, but problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's intrested I managed to find a workaround with the following code by making all unnecessary items gone at first, then invoking mLinearLayout.invalidate(), then making all needed items visible. There are still some minor overlaps, but they're barely observable now.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {
    if (tab.getPosition() != mLastSelectedTab) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View item = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (!isVisibleInTab(tab.getPosition(), i) {
                 item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        mLinearLayout.invalidate();
        for (int i = 0; i < mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View item = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (isVisibleInTab(tab.getPosition(), i) {
                 item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have a bunch of views inside a `ConstraintLayout`. By default they are stacking on top of each other by the order they have in the ConstraintLayout BUT sometimes when you have `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` and you hide/show the views, some of them overlap because of the order they have.

The way I managed to fix this is to set the appropriate elevation to each view.

For eg one view that you want to see above another, set the `android:elevation="2dp"` and for the one underneath set `android:elevation="1dp"`. This way the overlapping issue is fixed.

I know that it should consider the view's order from the layout itself but something weird happens when changing visibility.